# Wrapping all WordPress CSS files with a single <noscript id="deferred-styles">...</noscript>

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to wrap all CSS files together with `<noscript id='deferred-styles'>...</noscript>`.

I am interested to see, how would you do it in functions.php file.

The end result should look like this:

```html
<noscript id="deferred-styles">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file3.css">
</noscript>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Any suggestions?

Comment: What the article that you referenced doesn't mention is the browsers cache, web server configuration to gzip the files and the ability to minimise the files. What are the file sizes of the files that you want to combine?

Comment: I don't want to combine them. I just want to add <noscript id="deferred-styles"> before the first CSS file in the head and </noscript> after the last one.

Comment: why? do you know, where is using `noscript` tag?